# Find out if PostgreSQL uninstallation process is complete

Tags: windows, uninstallation

I am working a software uses PostreSQL 9.0 as the database (`postgresql-9.0.2-1-windows.exe`). We have a installer for installing PostgreSQL 9.0 and uninstalling PostgreSQL silently.
For `installation` we use this command

```
      C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\uninstall-postgresql.exe --mode unattended
```

is there any way to know that the process that starts the `uninstallation`has finished?

on my system the process that start is **uninstall-postgresql.exe** and followed by **_uninstall2660**.

both on [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=_unistall2660&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=NsU&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=postgres%20_uninstall2660&oq=postgres%20_uninstall2660&gs_l=serp.12...10739.12043.4.13189.2.2.0.0.0.0.165.294.0j2.2.0...0.0...1c.uhkfzSUnBSE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=5831ff9f2faa6ac6&biw=1366&bih=607) there is not sign of **_uninstall2660**.

Is checking if the `uninstall-postgresql.exe` is deleted a good ways?

How to correctly know if PostgreSQL installation has indeed finished?

Comment: Consider posting this on the PostgreSQL mailing list or EnterpriseDB forums . Link back to this question from your post, and add a link to your post here. The EnterpriseDB folks make the PostgreSQL installer and they're more active on the mailing list and forums than here on SO.

Comment: BTW, how you do you know you're uninstalling a PostgreSQL that you installed, not a PostgreSQL the user installed themselves? I'm not a big fan of bundling the EnterpriseDB installer inside program installers myself, I think they should be using the .zip packages and registering their own service with PostgreSQL on a non-default port, so they don't stomp on any PostgreSQL install the user has done themselves.

Comment: @CraigRinger `comment 1` : thank you, i will do the same.. `comment 2`- good question i didnt think of that though before,our clients are sure to have the postgresql that they have installed through our software (cannot disclose, how i know that).